# i want to call "OnChange Event" in javascript without refresh page?

Tags: javascript

i want to call "OnChange Event" in javascript without refresh page?

Comment: I want a puppy, without all of the cleanup duty?

Comment: But normally `onchange` won't refresh. Can't find the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
the_element.onChange();
```